# how to hold together a text of a item using list enviroment in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

With this LaTeX code:

```
\begin{list}
\item my first item title

    my first item content

\item my second item title

    my second item content

\end{list}
```

at the end of the page break in two parts a "item" like:

```
--------page 1--------
...
my first item title

my first item content

my second item title
----------------------

--------page 2--------
my second item content
----------------------
```

but i want to generate:

```
--------page 1--------
...
my first item title
my first item content

----------------------

--------page 2--------
my second item title
my second item content
----------------------
```

I don't want break a "item".
I try using \mbox but not found the linebreak.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End the title with `\nopagebreak\\` and no blank line between.